# How can i loop a process on camera frames (for example scan qr code using standard java Image QR detector)

Tags: java, android, android-camera, android-viewholder

basically, my goal is to build a QR scanner app that supports flashlight and lets me do some code when it detects something

I have tried some codes with no success

the first option was with CameraSource and I got stuck on turning on the flashlight because the CameraSource does not support flashlight and when I tried from the camera model it killed the CameraSource process

my second try was using the camera model with the SurfaceView but I did not find a way to loop on the image result properly

:) it is my first question on StackOverflow so I hope it's well written if you have any comment please write it below ...
and thank you for your time anyway

Comment: not an answer, but a famous zxing lib can ease your life, https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner

Comment: you can use Vision api for barcode scanner. Follow this link for more details:  https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.androidhive.info/2017/08/android-barcode-scanner-using-google-mobile-vision-building-movie-tickets-app/amp/